# Fill in a matrice in PHPEXCEL with data from database

Tags: php, phpexcel

I created in PHP a calendar to show to my boss my holidays.

The calendar works great.

I have to export the data of the calendar into an Excel sheet in this format :

[image]

I would like to know how can I put a cross in this table at March 09 if I take a holiday on march 9.

I tried this but my way seems to be not the best way :

I begin in the first cell and I browse all the cell, if I find a holiday, I put a cross.

**EDIT**
I change my code on Mark's advices (see below)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nom, prenom FROM utilisateurs";
$fiches = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$users = $fiches->execute();
$user_number = 0;

$res = $fiches->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$ligne = 0;
foreach($res as $user)
{
  $ligne = 1;
  $user_number++;
  $objPHPExcel->createSheet($user_number);
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($user_number);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($user->nom);

  $ligne++;
  $num_jours = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $annee_en_cours);

  $col = 'A';


     $sql = "SELECT jour, commentaire
             FROM reservations
             WHERE id_user = ".$user->id;
     $sql.= " ORDER BY jour";
     echo $sql.'<br />';
     $req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
     $execution = $req->execute();
     $res = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($res);
     echo '</pre>';
     if (count($res) > 0)
     {



       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($col.$ligne, $res[0]->jour);
     }
     echo $col.$ligne.'</br />';
     $col++;




  $ii = 1;
  for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'AF'; $col++)
  {
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($col.'1', $ii);

   }
}
```

I obtain this :

```
SELECT jour, commentaire FROM reservations WHERE id_user = 57 ORDER BY jour
```

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jour] => 2014_08_14_AM
            [commentaire] => 
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_10_02_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_10_16_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_11_05_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_11_06_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_03_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_10_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )
```

)

A2
SELECT jour, commentaire FROM reservations WHERE id_user = 58 ORDER BY jour

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jour] => 2014_06_03_AM
            [commentaire] => 
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_06_12_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_06_17_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_08_01_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_08_07_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_01_AM
        [commentaire] => test
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_03_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_11_AM
        [commentaire] => test
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_24_AM
        [commentaire] => test
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2015_01_01_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )
```

)

A2
SELECT jour, commentaire FROM reservations WHERE id_user = 59 ORDER BY jour

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jour] => 2014_12_03_AM
            [commentaire] => 
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jour] => 2014_12_04_AM
        [commentaire] => 
    )
```

)

A2
Exporation OK, veuillez cliquer pour sauvegarder le document 
This is not the best way, have you a idea plese ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to retrieve the list of all holidays for the year (one single database query to return all holiday rows, rather than 365/366 queries for each individual date) and loop through that resultset instead.... you should be able to work out the cell address to store an X from the date by extracting the month and date components